# From an ordinary deck of 52 cards, cards are drawn at random and with replacement.

Tags: probability

From an ordinary deck of 52 cards, cards are drawn at random and with replacement.
What is the probability that, of the first eight cards drawn, four are spades?

Comment: *with* replacement.  So it's hypothetically possible to draw the same card eight times?

Comment: Success: a spade. Probability of success: $1/4$. Independent trials: $8$. Probability of exactly $4$ successes, familiar?

Comment: You need the binomial distribution : If $X$~$B(n,p)$, we have $B(X=k)=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ for $k=0,...,n$